# search approximate match for a column in SQL or Python

Tags: mysql, sql, database, match, vlookup

My database in SQL has more than 2 million rows, with 2 column: products and description. and i have some data of description of products here.  i need to search all the rows in SQL that has description column is a approximate match(70%) with description data i have.
It look like this, for example

```
description
Bioti protein factor member
COVID 19 test kid
Antibody Superfamily 
....
```

Because it is description of medicines, so it is very complex with keyword. can i use keyword to find similar match?

Comment: You may want to look into [Full-Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16) for Sql Server or  similar tool for other DBMS. What is your DBMS? Tag the question accordingly.

Comment: It is MySQL. yes i will tag it